# Error, The distinct count function only accepts a column reference as an argument?

Tags: error-handling, count, powerbi, dax, measure

I am new to powerBI DAX. What is the root cause of the error message?

My code is as such:

```
Project Count (Actuals) = DISTINCTCOUNT(FLOOR('Forecast Summary'[Project_Ref],1))
```

Where Project Ref is a project version measure that is as followed:

```
Project Ref = Sum(~Project)
```

I did this because Floor didn't let me select the measure and it had to be a calculated field to reference.

Any recommendations?

[image: Error MSG]

[image: Measure]

Comment: `FLOOR` needs a number, not a column as the first argument. `DISTINCTCOUNT` needs a column, not a number as the first argument (same for `SUM`).

Comment: If the issue not solved yet, can you please share your sample data and expected output from them?